# Reversing a linked list - Iterative

Tags: visual-c++, linked-list, reverse

Need to reverse the list and then print it out, as of right now it prints the list in the same order, I've been searching everywhere, but I'm still stuck. I don't even know if it is reversing properly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class List;
class Iterator;

class Node{
public:
   /** 
      Constructs a node with a given data value.
      @param s the data to store in this node
   */
   Node(string s);
private:
   string data;
   Node* previous;
   Node* next;
friend class List;
friend class Iterator;
};

class List{
public:
   /**
      Constructs an empty list;
   */
   List();
   /**
      Appends an element to the list.
      @param data the value to append
   */
   void push_back(string data);
   /**
      Inserts an element into the list.
      @param iter the position before which to insert
      @param s the value to append
   */
   void insert(Iterator iter, string s);
   /**
      Reverses the order of the elements in the list.
   */
   void reverse(Node *&head);
   /**
      Removes an element from the list.
      @param iter the position to remove
      @return an iterator pointing to the element after the
      erased element
   */
   Iterator erase(Iterator iter);
   /**
      Gets the beginning position of the list.
      @return an iterator pointing to the beginning of the list
   */
   Iterator begin();
   /**
      Gets the past-the-end position of the list.
      @return an iterator pointing past the end of the list
   */
   Iterator end();
private:
   Node* first;
   Node* last;
friend class Iterator;
};

class Iterator{
public:
   /**
      Constructs an iterator that does not point into any list.
   */
   Iterator();
   /**  
      Looks up the value at a position.
      @return the value of the node to which the iterator points
   */
   string get() const;
   /**
      Advances the iterator to the next node.
   */
   void next();
   /**
      Moves the iterator to the previous node.
   */
   void previous();
   /**
      Compares two iterators
      @param b the iterator to compare with this iterator
      @return true if this iterator and b are equal
   */
   bool equals(Iterator b) const;
private:
   Node* position;
   List* container;
friend class List;
};

Node::Node(string s){  
   data = s;
   previous = NULL;
   next = NULL;
}

List::List(){  
   first = NULL;
   last = NULL;
}

void List::push_back(string data){  
   Node* new_node = new Node(data);
   if (last == NULL) // List is empty
   {  
      first = new_node;
      last = new_node;
   }
   else{  
      new_node->previous = last;
      last->next = new_node;
      last = new_node;
   }
}

void List::insert(Iterator iter, string s){  
   if (iter.position == NULL)   {  
      push_back(s);
      return;
   }

   Node* after = iter.position;
   Node* before = after->previous;
   Node* new_node = new Node(s);
   new_node->previous = before;
   new_node->next = after;
   after->previous = new_node;
   if (before == NULL) // Insert at beginning
      first = new_node;
   else
      before->next = new_node;
}

void List::reverse(Node *&head){
    if((head == NULL)||(head->next=NULL))
        return;
    Node *top = head;
    Node *tail = NULL;
    Node *curr = head;
    Node *temp = NULL;

    while(curr != NULL){
        temp = curr->next;
        curr->next = curr->previous;
        curr->previous = temp;
        if(temp == NULL){
            tail = curr;
        }
        curr = temp;
    } 
    temp = head;
    head = tail;
    tail = temp;
}

Iterator List::erase(Iterator iter){  
   assert(iter.position != NULL);
   Node* remove = iter.position;
   Node* before = remove->previous;
   Node* after = remove->next;
   if (remove == first)
      first = after;
   else
      before->next = after;
   if (remove == last)
      last = before;
   else
      after->previous = before;
   delete remove;
   Iterator r;
   r.position = after;
   r.container = this;
   return r;
}

Iterator List::begin(){  
   Iterator iter;
   iter.position = first;
   iter.container = this;
   return iter;
}

Iterator List::end(){  
   Iterator iter;
   iter.position = NULL;
   iter.container = this;
   return iter;
}

Iterator::Iterator(){  
   position = NULL;
   container = NULL;
}

string Iterator::get() const{  
   assert(position != NULL);
   return position->data;
}

void Iterator::next(){  
   assert(position != NULL);
   position = position->next;
}

void Iterator::previous(){  
   assert(position != container->first);
   if (position == NULL)
      position = container->last;
   else 
      position = position->previous;
}

bool Iterator::equals(Iterator b) const{  
   return position == b.position;
}

int main(){

   List staff;

   // Add orginal values to staff
   staff.push_back("Tom");
   staff.push_back("Dick");
   staff.push_back("Harry");
   staff.push_back("Juliet");

   Iterator pos;

   // Print all values
   for (pos = staff.begin(); !pos.equals(staff.end()); pos.next())
      cout << pos.get() << "\n";

   // Reverse the values
    Node* head = NULL;
    staff.reverse(head);

   // Print all values to show reverse
   cout << endl;
   for (pos = staff.begin(); !pos.equals(staff.end()); pos.next())
      cout << pos.get() << "\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: For one thing, your code is failing the test just as it enters the reverse method, since (head == NULL) and returning immediately

Comment: You didn't change the `List`'s `first` and `last` pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first statement of your `List::reverse` method checks whether `head == NULL` and if so, returns without modifying the list.  And you are passing in `NULL`.  So that's clearly a problem.  I don't understand why you think you need to pass in a `head` argument at all, but if you need to, you probably want to initialize it to the `first` of the list.